# How to use when condition in Ansible?

Tags: variables, ansible, conditional-statements

I cannot figure out this Ansible task

i run my playbook `ansible-playbook play.yml -e proxyHost=$proxyHost -e proxyPort=$proxyPort`

```
- name: Set proxy when provided
  set_fact: proxyproperty=" -Dhttp.proxyHost={{ proxyHost }} -Dhttp.proxyPort={{ proxyPort }} -Dhttps.proxyHost={{ proxyHost }} -Dhttps.proxyPort={{ proxyPort }} -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|{{ ip }}|{{ fqdn }}|{{ hostName }}"
  when: proxyHost is defined
```

So why is it when i have not set `$ProxyHost` this ansible task is still being triggered?  What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python (hence Ansible) differentiates between an undefined variable and a variable with an empty value.

You define the `proxyHost` variable in Ansible, but in case when `$proxyHost` is undefined in shell/environment, you assign `proxyHost` an empty value.

You need, for example, to compare it to an empty string:

```
when: proxyHost != ''
```